# Testing jQuery input mask in RSpec

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm trying to test a jQuery input mask using an rspec feature test.

The mask looks like:

```
$(function() {
  $('.format-date').inputmask('99/99/9999',{ 'placeholder': 'mm/dd/yyyy' }); 
})
```

And the feature test looks like

```
feature 'create a thing', type: :feature, js: true do
  scenario 'submit a new thing' do
    given_a_logged_in_admin
    visit '/thing/new'
    fill_in 'Effective Date', with: '11112020'

    click_button 'Submit'
```

I would expect the input mask to convert this to 11/11/2020. It doesn't appear to be doing that and additionally, I would like to make sure the page contains 11/11/2020 as well.

It works in the browser so it must be something to do with the test.

Comment: I use rspec for unit tests but not feature tests, so I'm not familiar with it in this context. However, I'm curious where the `expect` (or equivalent) part of your test is where you check if the input mask is 'working'? I would have thought somewhere between filling in the field and clicking the submit button, you would have had a test. But, I could be misunderstanding. Also, when you say, "It doesn't appear to be doing that", what are you observing? What makes you draw this conclusion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@jvillian sent me down the right path. I was trying to inspect the element and see if the input values had changed. I'm not sure why that didn't work, but if you google around trying to solve this problem you'll see people doing that to write their tests. However, when I tried to write a failing test instead of verify that the values had changed, I was able to write a test that works with jQuery input mask in rspec.

```
page.should have_field("object_effective_date", with: "11/11/2020")
```